# How to obtain marker position relative to HTML page

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, marker

I am using Google Maps API V3 for JavaScript, I do like to get a Marker's position relatively to my page in pixels (left, top), so I can add a custom label when hoving the mouse over my marker. How do I get that position?

Answer (score 0):

If your referring to getting the position of your mouse while you hover, use overlay in the listener to get the projection and the pixel coordinates. Overlays are objects on the map that are tied to latitude/longitude coordinates, so they move when you drag or zoom the map. If you want to place an image on a map, you can use a [GroundOverlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/groundoverlays#introduction) object or you can create your own [Custom Overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays#introduction) with the use of OverlayView class.

Sample code using OverlayView:

```
var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
overlay.draw = function() {};
overlay.setMap(map); // 'map' is new google.maps.Map(...)
```